# JSTL Reading if session value is set not working properly

Tags: java, session, servlets, jstl

I'm making some testing and I have faced strange problem, I'm setting session on servlet:

```
sessions.setAttribute("logged_in", "true");
```

This is my code on JSTL page, I want it to check if session name "logged_in" is set

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.logged_in}">
        <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <a href="/login">Login</a>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

But when I check my website, it outputs:

```
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
<a href="/login">Login</a>
```

It should output only login or logout, not both. Any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: Have you added jstl jars in your library and added `<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
           uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` in your jsp?

Comment: Right-click in the browser and choose "view page source". If you see c:choose inside, that means that the tags aren't executed by the server. See Zeeshan's comment.

Comment: Thanks! I had forgot to add library.

Answer (score 1):

Look's like the tags are not executed by the server.

Have you added `JSTL`jars in your library and added `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` in your jsp?